# Cannot figure out where project file variable is being set in MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2022

I'm working on a CSPROJ file which contains a package reference akin to the following:

```
<PackageReference Include="CustomNugetPackage">
      <IncludeAssets Condition=" '$(BooleanVariable)' == true ">compile</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

This variable is *not* set in the `PropertyGroup`, or anywhere else in the project file for that matter. I'm also running `msbuild` from the CLI myself, and I'm not setting `BooleanVariable` dynamically.

I know it does have a value of `true` during the build, because I added my own `Target` named `"LogMessage"` with `Message` elements inside of it to verify and then built with `msbuild ProjectFile /t:LogMessage`.

Running `$Env:BooleanVariable` in the relevant Powershell terminal also yielded nothing.

Where else could this variable be set? How does the build process know it's value even when I run using `msbuild` from the command line?

## Edit

As a response to the comments, proving that `msbuild` does not auto-set variables which are not explicitly declared.

On a regular console app:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <AnotherVariable Condition=" '$(BooleanVariable)' == true ">ABCDE</AnotherVariable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="LogMessage" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="BooleanVariable = $(BooleanVariable)"/>
    <Message Text="AnotherVariable = $(AnotherVariable)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>=
```

Compile with `msbuild TestProject.csproj`, observe the logged message:

```
LogMessage:
  BooleanVariable =
  AnotherVariable =
```

Comment: Do you have any `*.targets` files in your solution? Or any other `Import` lines in your csproj?

Comment: @DavidG yes, but none of them contain the string `BooleanVariable`. No `Import` lines in the CSPROJ either.

Comment: Maybe its never being set/declared and it defaults to true? But I doubt it.  I can't find any kind of documentation of that behavior at least.

Comment: @TimothyG. I went ahead and tested it. Please see edit to OP. `msbuild` does not auto-set unassigned properties like that.

Comment: This would be a good use for [MSBuild Structured Log Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/) since you can search for `BooleanVariable` and see exactly where it is set.

Comment: Shouldn't `" '$(BooleanVariable)' == true "` be `" '$(BooleanVariable)' == 'true' "` or just `"$(BooleanVariable)"`. Not sure I'm remembering the rules...

Comment: @Kit, I thought the same.  While non-conventional, it does seem to work without the quotes (tested with MSBuild version 17.4.1+9a89d02ff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these types of situations, preprocessing is your friend. The following command preprocesses the CSPROJ and outputs the result in a file called `output.txt`:

`msbuild /pp:output.txt .\TestProject.csproj`

I checked the contents of `output.txt` and it turns out `BooleanVariable` was being set in a separate file, `Directory.Build.props`.